# How to find out the configuration need for the server?

Tags: sql-server, architecture, sql-server-administration

We are creating 2 sets of 2 new server(2 for prod 2 for test) and one server will have database engine and SSIS and the other server will have SSAS and SSRS.

How can I find out what configuration I need for the server and what RAM, Size of Disk, What processor ?

IF I want to learn is there anything out there I can reference into.

There will be up to 80 different database approximately 5-15 GB.

We are planning to get sql server 2008-r2 or sql server 2012

Comment: Why would you go for something that old and not SQL Server 2014? (or maybe even 2016)

Comment: When choosing the hardware, everything depends on the usage, not the size of the database(s). If you want to read detailed information about selecting CPUs, Glenn Berry has a lot of blog posts in that area: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/ for the other questions, well, people do that for living, so I don't think you're going to get any detailed answer from here.

Comment: @JamesZ : May be we will be using 2012 but I don't think, they will let us use the server 2014 or 2016.

Comment: Build it out on VMs (instead of physical servers) and adjust the configuration as needed.